# Which one is the stable version of opendaylight?

Tags: opendaylight

Currently, I am using Boron version of Opendaylight. But its document says that 
"This document is for a release of Opendaylight that is no longer supported."

Can anyone suggest which version of Opendaylight is best for studying Quality of Services?

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of what you’re trying to do with OpenDaylight, you should always use one of the supported releases; in general, we support the last two releases. Currently, those are [Oxygen](https://www.opendaylight.org/what-we-do/current-release/oxygen) and [Fluorine](https://www.opendaylight.org/what-we-do/current-release/fluorine). I recommend Fluorine; Oxygen has just had its last service release and will no longer be updated.

You’ll always find our supported releases on [the main download page](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/downloads.html).